# Mapping a vector to Eigen Affine3f

Tags: eigen

I have a raw floating array of 12 elements which contain an affine transformation matrix and I would like to map it to an Affine3f object.

The input floating point array actually stores the parameter in a row major sequence, while the Affine3f stores it in a column major format, if I am correct.

Is there nice Eigen recommended way to map such an array to the Affine3f object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either cast it as a `Transform<float,3,AffineCompact,RowMajor>` which is ugly, or copy the coefficients using a `Map`:

```
AffineCompact3f A;
A = Map<Matrix<float,3,4,RowMajor> >(data);
```